# What is the meaning of "what goes to" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Screenplay

Husband and wife are talking about their ill son:

A: He can hardly eat anything and here we are, wasting our time with this shit.

B: Oh yeah?
Like you have any idea **what goes to** feed him.

What is the meaning of "what goes to" in this context?

Comment: More generally expressed like this: What goes into feeding him. (the progressive tense) You may want to make the change to your screenplay. [A husband and wife are talking about their ill son.]

Comment: To me, a Canadian, this seems like a mistake where "what goes into feeding him" was intended. It could be British English that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: It would be helpful to know when and where this screenplay is from and when and where it is supposed to take place. That's not a sentence that Americans would parse as grammatically correct in modern AmE, so I'm assuming it's older or maybe supposed to be set in a city/country that has a specific dialect?

Answer (score -1):

What things or actions done contribute to the outcome being discussed. E.g. what effort, money, time, special food (etc) - probably, but without much more context (e.g. much more of the screenplay) it is impossible to say. I might have a 1936 Rolls Royce, and might say that few people understand what *goes to* (or *goes into*) keeping it on the road.